# Select Query with Group by and Having condition

Tags: sql, excel, finance

> Blockquote

I'm currently trying to find a way to validate data for my own small company, and we have a complicated security data file where there are multiple payouts for the same investment ID. My end goal is to have a message in our system that pops up whenever we have a payout value that is differnt or not the same (Pertaining to each individual investment ID).

So, right now I'm trying to make a query that recognizes when there is an investment ID that has a differant payout value (invesment ID's can have multiple payouts but all payouts must be the exact same value). I'm still a bit new to sql so any advice would be much appreciated.

Here is an sized down example of the data file I'm using [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UItxA.png). In this example investment ID 455 and 543 should flag wrong, because investment 455 has a NULL value and investment 543 has two different values.

I have code set up that makes sense logically but wont run properly due to payout_value in my having statement not being an aggregate or in the group by. If you have any tips or or ways to solve this problem I would be extremely grateful towards you.

```
Select Investment_ID, Payout_# From investment_table
 
Group BY investment_ID, Payout_# 
 
Having Sum(payout_value) / Count(payout_#) <> payout_value 

Order by investment_id, payout_#
```

enter code here

Thanks,
Joe

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be looking for `investment_id`s that have at least one null `payout_value`, or at least two different `payout_values`.

If so, you can use aggregation, and filter with a `having` clause:

```
select investment_id
from investment_table
group by investment_id
having 
    min(payout_value) <> max(payout_value) 
    or max(case when payout_value is null then 1 else 0 end) = 1
```

On the other hand, if you want all rows for the offending `investiment_id`s, you can use aggregation:

```
select *
from (
    select 
        i.*,
        min(payout_value) over(partition by investiment_id) min_payout_value,
        max(payout_value) over(partition by investiment_id) max_payout_value,
        max(case when payout_value is null then 1 else 0 end) over(partition by investiment_id) cnt_null_payout_value
    from investment_table i
) i
where min_payout_value <> max_payout_value or cnt_null_payout_value = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

> In this example investment ID 455 and 543 should flag wrong, because investment 455 has a NULL value and investment 543 has two different values.

You can use aggregation like this:

```
select Investment_ID
from investment_table
group by investment_ID
having count(payout_value) <> count(*) or       -- ever NULL
       min(payout_value) <> max(payout_value)   -- different values
order by Investment_ID;
```